# How to get NSData From Hex String?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I need to send data over `melodyManager` & free from NonHexCharacters,

I already gone throught link [How to convert an NSData into an NSString Hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string)

[NSData from hex String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231926/nsdata-from-hex-string)

In Both links i am not able to get NonHexFree charater data.

My input string is this,

`0x0009 0xB0 0xFD 0xC2 0xA1 0x06 0x01%@040404 0x01 0xss1 0xhh 0xyy1`

I need to convert this string into NSData which is free from nonhex characters i mean data should get only of hex string like from 0-9 symbols & A, B, C, D, E, F (alternatively a, b, c, d, e, f) and also remove space with 0x prefixes & output string should be `0009B0FDC2A10601040404111`

then it should get converted to `NSData'

Comment: This question is a little too abstract. What is melodyManager, what is NonHexFree? What did you do? Please show us code and depict where you got stuck.

Comment: So what is the result you would expect? Is it "000090B00FD0C20A100600104040400101001"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7318062/1091539

Comment: Yes nearly Clean a hex string by removing `spaces` and `0x` chars, `0x` because usually it is involving as a prefix thus output data should be get from this string only 0009B0FDC2A10601040404111.

Comment: @Mutawe i gone through your link too ... its not cleaning non hex characters.

Comment: I think you have to look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072744/checking-for-multiple-characters-in-nsstring

Comment: @Mukesh Can you add your code for scanning those nonhex characters?

Comment: Please edit your question, giving the wanted result from your input string, because it's clearly unclear what you want. Also, from where does come your input string, because your issue could be from getting that value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cleaning nonHex characters check this,

```
NSString *input = @"0x0009 0xB0 0xFD 0xC2 0xA1 0x06 0x01%@040404 0x01 0xss1 0xhh 0xyy1";
```

I am considering that you don't required '0x' into your case.

```
NSString * output = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0x" withString:@""
                                                        options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)];
NSString * hexChars = @"0123456789abcdefABCDEF";
NSCharacterSet *hexc = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:hexChars];
NSCharacterSet *invalidHexc = [hexc invertedSet];
NSString * allHex = [[output componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidHexc] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Then resultant hexstring pass to scan hexString & append into `NSMUtableData` then convert it into NSData,

```
//Check condition if required `allHex.lenght != nil`

NSMutableData *result = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i+2 <= allHex.length; i+=2) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, 2);
    NSString* hexStr = [allHex substringWithRange:range];
    NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];
    unsigned int intValue;
    [scanner scanHexInt:&intValue];
    unsigned char uc = (unsigned char) intValue;
    [result appendBytes:&uc length:1];
}
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithData:result];
```

Comment: It is perfectly working for me, hey @Mukesh can you tell me?why you are scaning string again?

Comment: Just go to definition of `scanHexInt :` method, its Optionally prefixed with "0x" or "0X"